# Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop freezes after idle for a while

Tags: gnome, 20.10

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 on my laptop and it seems every time I leave it for an extended time, when I come back, the power light is on, but the screen is black and doesn't appear to respond even to Ctl + Alt + F#, nor do the lights change if I press Caps Lock or Num Lock keys.  Nothing telling seems to be in dmesg or syslog.

I had initially thought it might have something to do with the USB-C dock and the multi-monitor setup I was using, but it still happens with nothing else attached.

I've done up a cron job to output time + idle time every minute to text file to see if I can get some idea of how long it takes or if it's even consistent; so far I've made 37 minutes and been able to wake it.  Will update when I know more.

Any other ideas about what I can do to get to the bottom of this?  Since it never happens while I'm using it, and only after extended idle, I presume power management is playing a part?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. It started after upgrading to 20.04. I recently upgraded to 20.10, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your specific issue, but my laptop would constantly lockup on idle.  My laptop was originally a Dell Elitebook with 4 Intel i5 CPUs running at 2.4 GHz and 4 gig RAM memory.  I finally figured out that the swap file was killing my machine simply because 4 GB of RAM was not enough.  I doubled it to 8 GB and I've never had any problems with locking up since.